# How can I make my navigation bar have a smooth dropdown effect?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Basically, I am trying to create a navigation bar that has a smooth dropdown effect. I have already created the navigation bar, but am struggling to make the dropdown effect. I would like the dropdown effect to be shown when the user hovers over the tab in the navigation bar called "Works." When hovered, I would like there to be 2 separate tabs that the user can click to navigate. I would like the navigation bar's theme to remain consistent, such as the font, color, and scroll effect. How can I do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Here is my code.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    var header = document.querySelector("header");
    header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
 })
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
}
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
    min-height: 200vh;
  background-color: #000;
}
h3 {
    color: #3F69CA
}
/* Navbar */
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s;
    padding: 40px 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header.sticky {
    padding: 5px 100px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header .logo {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header ul li a {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
header.sticky .logo, header.sticky ul li a {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <header>
        <a class="" href="#"></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#works">Works</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#test">Test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </header>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own pop-up and adjust the pop-up position according to the mouse position so that the pop-up menu will not be disturbed by the effect.

**try this**

```js
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    var header = document.querySelector("header");
    header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
 })


var worksbtn = document.querySelector("#works"),altmenu = document.querySelector(".altmenu")
worksbtn.onmouseover = function(e){
    altmenu.style.top = e.clientY +30+"px"; //or  AA px
    altmenu.style.left = e.clientX-50+"px";//or  BB px
    altmenu.style.display ="block" 
    animeOpen()
}
altmenu.onmouseout = function(e){
    animeClose()
}


function animeOpen(){
    let i = 0;
   let openinterval =  setInterval(() => {
        altmenu.style.height = i +"px"

        i=i+10
        
        if( i == 180) {clearInterval(openinterval)}
    }, 1);
   

}
function animeClose(){
    let i = altmenu.style.height.replace("px","");
   let closeinterval =  setInterval(() => {
        altmenu.style.height = i +"px"

        i=i-10
        if( i == 0) {clearInterval(closeinterval);altmenu.style.display ="none"   }
    }, 1);
   

}
```

```css
     * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
}
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
    min-height: 200vh;
  background-color: #000;
}
h3 {
    color: #3F69CA
}
/* Navbar */
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s;
    padding: 40px 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header.sticky {
    padding: 5px 100px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header .logo {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header ul li a {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
header.sticky .logo, header.sticky ul li a {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.altmenu{position:absolute;z-index:999;width:100px;display:none;background-color:#333;}
.altmenuli{float: left;width:100px;height:30px;border-bottom:1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<body>
        <header>
        <a class="" href="#"></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li id="works">
                <a href="#works">Works</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#test">Test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

      
  </header>
  <ul class="altmenu">

</ul>
  </body>
```